# Mobx and observing array changes from third-party library

Tags: mobx

I have a class with @observable properties and can react to local observable changes OK. The class also makes use of a third-party library that has a method OrderBookSnapshot() which returns a snapshot of the most recent array, but is not observable. [I gather](https://mobx.js.org/best/react.html) that I cannot assign non-observable arrays to the observable property. But is there a way to observe non-observable arrays from another library without making that library observable itself?

```
export class MyOrderBook {

  @observable
  private offerBook: any[]
  private cmeClient // third-party class

  constructor(symbol: string[]) {
    this.offerBook = []
    this.cmeClient = new cmeClient.OrderBook(symbol[0])
  }

  // Calls third-party method and returns updated array
  UpdateOrderbookSync() {
    // This is not observable    
    this.offerBook = this.cmeClient.OrderBookSnapshot()
  }
}
```

Comment: Update: I added the @action.bound decorator to the UpdateOrderbookSync() method and it appears to have the desired side-effect. With the exception that the array lengths do not match. Where the '@obserable' local array has an array length that is ~28% longer than the 'data fetch' array. Will need to debug to see what is going on there.

Comment: ^ The lengths do in fact match if I explicitly print .length, the differences appear to be that if there are multiple entries with the same price level, the  book object count accounts for the number of entries at a specific price level.

Answer (score 0):

Adding potential solution to my answer. The @action.bound decorator appears to give the desired result. Though it is not clear if this is the best way to update an observable array, since most of the array is unchanged.

```
  @action.bound
  UpdateOrderbookSync() {
    // This is not observable    
    this.offerBook = this.cmeClient.OrderBookSnapshot()
  }
```